# How to update user address with wp_update_user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have create my own custom sign up form on my website. My website is a WordPress Custom theme with WooCommerce. I am trying to update the users address using wp_update_user but according to this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user 'address_1' is not a field for this function. So how can I update the users address programmatically?

This is my attempt with wp_update_user:

```
wp_update_user(
    array(
        'ID'            => $user_id,
        'first_name'    => $first_name,
        'last_name'     => $last_name,
        'address_1'     => $address_line_one
    )
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `set_billing_address_1` or `set_shipping_address_1` from the `WC_Customer` class.

```
$customer = new WC_Customer($user_id);
$customer->set_billing_address_1($address_line_one);
$customer->save();
```

For more information: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Customer.html

Comment: Yes that is the best woocommerce way…

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the update user meta function. see below link and its usage

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta

Comment: This method will be useful to me for other stuff, so thanks. But this doesn't update the user information in the users section of the dashboard it only updates it in the user_meta table